# What is the equivalent or workaround for a typedef in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am coding a VB.NET application which heavily deals with a collection type. See the code below:

```
Dim sub_Collection As System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, 
                             System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection)
```

I have to type the above line for so many times. If I changed the collection type, then I have to make the change for all the instances. So if there is a way to use "a typedef equivalent", then I can get rid of all these problems. I tried with imports, but it is only for namespaces and it can't be used for classes. Any helping hand will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using VB 2008, windows XP. The application type is windows forms(VB).

**EDIT:**
    I made some tries based on code_gray's below answer.

This is the first try.

```
Imports dictionary_WaterBill = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of WaterBill))
Structure WaterBill
...
...
End Structure
```

I got the error as

```
Error:Type 'WaterBill' is not defined.
```

This is try 2.

```
Structure WaterBill
...
...
End Structure
Imports dictionary_WaterBill = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String,     
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of WaterBill))
```

I got the error as

```
Error:'Imports' statements must precede any declarations.
```

Anybody is welcome to shed a light on this issue.

Comment: One of the things I really, really hate about .Net is the absence of typedefs.  Sorry - but I think your answer is "No"... :(

Comment: I've been writing .NET code for years and I've never needed or wanted a typedef. One of us must be doing something wrong.

Comment: One of the things I really, really like about Pascal is its type system.  C/C++ typedefs are pale in comparison. I guess .Net's reply is "wrap it in a class".  If so - that sucks. Prabhakaran's "collections" is an excellent example why.  IMHO...  PS: just because you've been using screws with a hammer for years doesn't mean you wouldn't benefit from a screwdriver :)

Comment: In response to your edit, note that I said to place the `Imports` statements **at the top of your code file**. The compiler error message is telling you the exact same thing: "Error:'Imports' statements must precede any declarations." What more helping hand do you need?

Comment: @Cody Sorry, I forgot to add some more code. Now check the EDIT.

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is simply to add an [`Imports` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) for the two namespaces that you're using. Right off the bat, that eliminates half of your long type identifiers.

At the top of your code file, place the lines:

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
```

And then your declaration can be changed to:

```
Dim sub_Collection As Dictionary(Of String, Collection)
```

I'd recommend this approach because it still uses the standard names, which keeps your code easy to read for other programmers.

---

The alternative is to use an `Imports` statement to declare an alias. Something like:

```
Imports GenericDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String,
                            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection)
```

And then you could change your declaration to:

```
Dim sub_Collection As GenericDict
```

*** By the way, in order to get either of these samples to compile, you'll have to specify a type for the `Collection`, such as `Collection(Of String)`.

Comment: The main problem is dictionary. It demands the declaration of parameters. You have to explicitly say like dictionary(Of String,System.Collections.etc.Collections). I also have to declare dictioneries for some other collections.

Comment: Q: Also, wouldn't "Imports MyDictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String,
                            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection)" have to be repeated in every source module that wanted to use the alias?

Comment: @paulsm4 - If you want to have the alias apply to the entire project you can put it in the project's imported namespaces.  You do that under the project's Properties -> References.  Enter `MyDictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection)` in the "Imported Namespaces" text box and then click on "Add User Import".  You can then use MyDictionary throughout your entire project, with no per-file Imports needed.  (Nothing like a decade between comments).

Comment: There's absolutely nothing in any "modern" language like Java or C# that matches the simplicity and elegance of declaring types and subtypes in Pascal ... or even Ada...

Answer (score 2):

Create an inherited class with no content:

```
Class WaterBillDictionary
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of WaterBill))
End Class

Structure WaterBill
    ...
End Structure
```

If you want a particular constructor, you'll have to write a wrapper that accepts the parameters and passes them to the base constructor.  For example:

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(capacity As Integer)
    MyBase.New(capacity)
End Sub
```

If you ever need to change the name of `WaterBillDictionary`, you can use Visual Studio's rename feature to automatically change the name in the entire solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that while the inherited class will be substitutable for the base, the base class will be neither substitutable *nor castable* to the derived class.

Comment: of course - thats the very core concept of inheritance .. somewhat needless to say